# Windows Explorer not showing film frame for .mp4

Tags: windows-explorer, mp4, thumbnails, mp4box

Anyone knows what part of registry is related to this film frame? I installed and uninstalled mp4box, avidemux, YAMB try to set default aspect ratios but failed, and now I have a new problem.

[image: mp4 not showing film frame]

Comment: I don’t understand what you problem is; I see thumbnails for both of the video files in your screenshot. Are you asking how to get the sprocket perforations in the thumbnail? (I would think most people would want to know how to *get rid* of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about getting the sprocket perforations on the thumbnail, I would suggest using [Icaros](http://shark007.net/tools.html). It lets you specify file types to generate thumbnails for (including various video formats for which thumbnails are not generated by default). If you add `.mp4` to its list, then it may change how the thumbnail is generated (i.e., use WMP to generate it like is done for `.wmv` files).

You can also customize the appearance of video thumbnails with [Thumbnailer Lite](http://www.captrue.com/thumbnailerlite.html):

[image: Thumbnailer Lite]

Comment: Also, there is a program that can customize various aspects of video previews (including sprocket perforations), but I just cannot seem to find it. I have a copy of it somewhere and will find it tonight.

Comment: General observation: what I can't understand is, when one is talking about thumbnails that by definition are quite small, why would one want sprocket perforations to obstruct what little can be seen of the actual image?

Comment: @Karan, consistency?

Comment: Hmm, I *guess*, although I agree with your comment above, that most people would actually want to know how to get *rid* of them.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the Icaros suggestion, but do you happen to know if it will work properly in Windows 8 as well?

Comment: yes, it worked like a charm, after activating and de-activating the sprocket perforations are shown. I guess it is consistency. @Karan it works in Windows 8 Release Preview.

Comment: Thanks, @Synetech , if you find the aspect ratio changer program remember to tell me.